# How to gather code to be used in a htmlentities() function without rendering beforehand?

Tags: php, html

To put my question into context, I'm working on an entirely static website where 'post' pages are created by myself manually - there's no CMS behind it. Each page will require a `<pre>` `<code>` block to display code as text in a styled block. This could be very few - several which is why I'm trying to do this for ease.

Here's what I've done -

```html
function outputCode($code) {
    return "<pre class='preBlock'><code class='codeBlock'>".htmlentities($code)."</code></pre>";
}
```

The code works as expected and produces an expected outcome when it's able to grab code. My idea is to somehow wrap the code for the code block with this function and echo it out for the effect, fewer lines and better readability.

As I'm literally just creating pages as they're needed, is there even a way to create the needed code blocks with such function to avoid having to manually repeat all the code for each code block? Cheers!

EDIT:

I was previously using this function and it was working great as I was pulling code from .txt documents in a directory and storing the code for code blocks in a variable with file_get_contents(). However, now, I'm trying to get the function to work by manually inputting the code into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Wrapping the function input in ' ' completely slipped my mind! It works just fine now!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to re-use your `outputCode` function in several different PHP files, corresponding to posts.  If yes, you could put this 1 function in its own file, called `outputcode.php` for example, and then do

```
include "outputcode.php";
```

in every post/PHP file that needs to re-use this function.  This will pull in the code, from the one common/shared file, for use in each post/PHP file that needs it. Or maybe I'm misreading your last paragraph :(

Comment: Not quite, for fewer lines on each post page that requires several code blocks, I want to re-use the function. I can include it but actually giving the function code to use without it rendering and trying to output something is giving me problems and the only solution I can think of right now is just to scrap the idea and repeat the same `<pre>` `<code>` process for every required code block.